# Breadth- and Depth-first search code

Tags: c, algorithm, breadth-first-search, depth-first-search

Here is my breadth-first search (`bfs`) and depth-first search (`dfs`) code for graph traversal. Please give me some constructive reviews on it.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>  
#define null 0

typedef struct node//node of a linked list
{
    struct vertex* info;//info part of node
    struct node* next;// next pointer of a node
}*nodeptr;

typedef struct edge
{
    int weight;
    struct vertex * point;
    struct edge *next;
}*eptr;

typedef struct vertex
{
    int degree;
    int info;
    int status;
    struct vertex * next;
    struct edge *point;
    struct vertex *parent;
}* vptr;

typedef struct graph
{
    struct vertex *start;
    int *directed;
}Graph;

typedef struct queue
{
    nodeptr front;//front pointer of a queue
    nodeptr rear;//rear pointer of a queue
} *QUEUE;

QUEUE qwe;

void insert_node(Graph *g,int x)
{
    vptr p=(vptr)malloc(sizeof(struct vertex));
    p->degree=0;
    p->info=x;
    p->point=null;
    p->status=1;
    p->next=g->start;
    g->start=p;

    return;
}

vptr find(vptr p,int x)
{
    while(p!=null)
    {
        if(p->info==x)
        return p;
        p=p->next;
    }
    return null;
}

void insert_edge(Graph *g,int a,int b,int directed)
{
    vptr loca;
    vptr locb;
    eptr p;
    eptr q;
    loca=find(g->start,a);
    locb=find(g->start,b);

    if(loca==null||locb==null)
    {
        printf("void insertion");
        return;
    }

    p=loca->point;
    q=null;

    while(p!=null)
    {
        q=p;
        p=p->next;
    }

    p=(eptr)malloc(sizeof(struct edge));
    p->point=locb;
    p->next=null;
    if(q!=null)
    q->next=p;
    else
    loca->point=p;
    if(directed)
    return;
    else
    insert_edge(g,b,a,1);
}

void delete_edge(Graph *g,int a,int b,int directed)
{
    vptr loca=find(g->start,a);
        vptr locb=find(g->start,b);
    eptr p=loca->point;
    eptr q=null;
    while(p->point!=locb)
    {
        q=p;
        p=p->next;
    }
    if (q==null)
    loca->point=null;
    else
    q->next=p->next;
    free(p);
    return;
}

void process_vertex_early(vptr x)
{
    printf("%d ",x->info);
}

void process_vertex_late(vptr x)
{

}

void process_edge(vptr x,vptr y)
{
    //printf("%d %d\n",x->info,y->info);
}

int empty_queue()//if queue is empty then return 1
{
    if (qwe->front==null)
    return 1;
    else
    return 0;
}

void insert_queue(vptr x)
{
    nodeptr p=(nodeptr)malloc(sizeof(struct node));//allocate new memory space to be added to queue
    p->next=null;
    p->info=x;
    if(empty_queue())//if the queue is empty,front and rear point to the new node
    {
        qwe->rear=p;
        qwe->front=p;
        return;     
    }
    qwe->rear->next=p;
    qwe->rear=p;
        //rear points to the new node
    return; 
}

vptr delete_queue()
{
    vptr x;

    if(empty_queue())//if queue is empty then it is the condition for underflow
    {
        printf("underflow\n");
        return;
    }

    nodeptr p=qwe->front;//p points to node to be deleted
    x=p->info;//x is the info to be returned
    qwe->front=p->next;

    if(qwe->front==null)//if the single element present was deleted
        qwe->rear=null;

    free(p);
    return x;
}
```

**BFS**

```
void bfs(Graph *g)
{
    vptr q=g->start;
    vptr x;
    vptr y;
    eptr p;
    while(q!=null)
    {
        q->status=1;
        q=q->next;
    }
    g->start->status=2;
    insert_queue(g->start);

    while(!(empty_queue()))
    {
        x=delete_queue();
        process_vertex_early(x);
        x->status=3;
        p=x->point;

        while(p!=null)
        {
            y=p->point;

            if(y->status!=3||g->directed)
                process_edge(x,y);

            if(y->status==1)
            {
                y->status=2;
                y->parent=x;
                insert_queue(y);
            }

            p=p->next;
        }
        process_vertex_late(x);
    }
    return;
}
```

**DFS**

```
void dfs(Graph *g,vptr x)
{
    //  if(finished)return;
    //  x->entry_time=++time;
    eptr p=x->point;
    vptr y;
    process_vertex_early(x);

    while(p!=null)
    {
        y=p->point;

        if(y->status==1)
        {
            process_edge(x,y);
            y->status=2;
            y->parent=x;
            dfs(g,y);
        }

        else if((y->status==2&&x->parent!=y||g->directed))
        {
            process_edge(x,y);
        }
        //  if(finished)return;
        p=p->next;
    }

    process_vertex_late(x);
    x->status=3;
    //x->exit_time=++time;
    return;
}
```

Comment: I can understand how your graph hangs together. You will need to add comments the describe how `node/edge/vertex/graph` hang together to build a graph.

Comment: Have you tested it at all?  In `delete_edge` you have `if (q=null)` which your compiler should warn you about.

Comment: yesyes (q=null) should be (q==null)

Comment: But did you test it? I would expect that sort of error to turn up quite quickly in tests (quite apart from the compiler telling you of it).

Comment: It would be easier to review this code if there was an example `main()` program that created a graph and then ran the traversal functions over it.  It is a lot harder to work out what's required and expected when you don't provide an SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)).

Answer (score 4):

Some comments, in no particular order:

You are inconsistent in spacing and in positioning of '*', which makes the code look
rather scrappy.

It is generally less confusing not to hide pointers behind type definitions.
Admittedly you use 'ptr' in the type names, so this lessens the harm.  But
when I compare your definition and use of `eptr`:

```
typedef struct edge
{
    ...
}*eptr;

// function:
{
    eptr p;
```

to a more normal:

```
typedef struct edge
{
    ...
} Edge;

// function:
{
    Edge *e;
```

I have no hesitation in saying the latter is more easily understood (bearing
in mind that the function will probably not be near to (or even in the same
file as) the definition.

Also on types, your `QUEUE` would be better written `Queue` as upper case
names are usually kept for #define constants.

Other issues

- don't cast the return of `malloc`.  This can be harmful and is never
  necessary in C.  Also check the return from `malloc` is not NULL and handle
  such failures.
- add spaces around operators ('==', '=', etc)
- indent the code properly
- using braces around single line statements avoids some common errors.
- `empty_queue` is badly named.  Prefer `is_empty` or something indicating
  that the return is a truth value.  Also `empty_queue` and `delete_queue`
  should have a `void` parameter list.
- `delete_queue` seems to delete on entry from the queue, not the whole queue
  as its name would suggest.
- `delete_edge` does not use its parameter `directed`.
- `process_vertex_early`, `process_vertex_late` and `process_edge` appear to
  be unfinished.
- `bfs` has three `while` loops.  That is seldom necessary and indicates that
  you could extract some of the functionality to separate helper functions
  and hence make the function more understandable.
- both `dfs` and `bfs` call incomplete functions `process_vertex_early` and
  `process_vertex_late`, which makes me think this code is generally
  incomplete.